# How do I use Color[] Colors in C#?

Tags: c#, colors

Ok so , I found this cool code and I can't use it. You see ... We have to input an Image 
which I can do it but we also need to Input Colors which I dont know how to do it...

```
public static Bitmap Colorize(Bitmap Image, Color[] Colors)
{
    if (Colors.Length < 256)
       return null;
    Bitmap TempBitmap = new Bitmap(Image.Width, Image.Height);
    for (int x = 0; x < Image.Width; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Image.Height; ++y)
        {
           int ColorUsing = Image.GetPixel(x, y).R;
            TempBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Colors[ColorUsing]);
        }
    }
    return TempBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Would be fun to know what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: @Etienne: Isn't it obvious?  It does a "Colorize."  :D  But seriously, it looks like it redraws some image onto a new one using a different color palette.

Comment: @Cody: What the heck are you saying?

Comment: @Cody maybe it was edited but ColorUsing is defined as an int. Why is this question getting voted down? The method takes an array of colors  and a bitmap image and based on the Red component of the existing image it selects a new color for the returned bitmap. I'm not saying it's a great method but I don't see anything wrong with the question.

Comment: This Code is supposed to turn a black and white image to color image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in an array of Color objects, as follows:

```
        Bitmap bitmapToColorize = new Bitmap(@"C:\bitmap.bmp");
        Color[] colors = new Color[2];
        colors[0] = Color.Blue;
        colors[1] = Color.Green;

        Colorize(bitmapToColorize, colors);
```

Of course, looking at the method, it looks like you need to fill the Color array with at least 256 colors.

I would recommend you read up on [arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Of course the array should be at least Color[256] so the method doesn't return null. But this appears to be the answer the questioner is looking for. +1

Comment: ok so what do I have to do for the things not to return null ?

Comment: You need to use an array of 256 colors.